# Segmenting trees from a LiDAR file (LAS) in R language

Tags: r, lidar

Are there ways of using data from the LiDAR file (LAS format), to do tree segmentation? I tried to study this question. I tried use example of processing .las file in R on this resource http://www.wvview.org/spatial_analytics/lidar/_site/index.html

However, an example of how to do segmentation by tree was not given here (only just mentioned about it possibility). So maybe someone already had experience in segmenting tree from lidar files and can share it or help find an example of how it is done in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a tutorial for tree segmentation in the lidR documentation:

[Individual tree dectection and segmentation](https://r-lidar.github.io/lidRbook/itd-its.html)